# SSRS map feature does not pick up my spatial data

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, geometry, maps, ssrs-2012

I have a query that combines longitude and latitude values into a column  so that it can be used in a map on Data Tools ( Microsoft Visual Studio). However no matter what I try in my code , when creating a map , the map wizard states that there is no spatial data in my dataset. Here is how my query looks like. I have also found that mySQL is very restrictive compared to t-SQL when imported into Data tools.

```
select City,ST_AsText( POINT(NewLongitude,NewLatitude)) AS SpatialData,POINT(NewLongitude,NewLatitude) AS SpatialDataWithoutConversion
from (
select   City,latitude, Longitude, 
         (latitude)-10 AS NewLatitude, 
         (longitude)-20 AS NewLongitude,
from table1
where state = 'Alabama' 
Group By City
     )
```

[Here is a screenshot of my returned data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3vTq.png)

[image]

What is the issue here? Why wont SSRS pick up the spatial data in my results? I have found that mySQL only has a geometry data type as opposed to also geography one found in T-sql. I have tried creating a column of geometry data type and adding my spatial data to it but that didnt seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I ve come to the conclusion that it is impossible to create spatial data with MySQL as it does not allow for the creation of a column with the geography data type cause it doesnt exist in mySQl.